# How to derive properties from parameter of generic class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to implement a mixin-like class that applies all properties of an input argument onto itself in the constructor. The issue I have is that I cannot find a way to properly type such a class.

Ideally, I would like to hit all 3 points:

1. **Works** — Is simply, technically viable.
2. **Direct** — Passing a type parameter to `Food` would make it derive all the properties (along with classes (`Steak`) that extend `Food`).
3. **Stable** — Doesn't rely on undefined TypeScript behaviour.

```
class Thing<T extends Thing<any>> {
  public declare thing: true;

  constructor(public input: T) {}
}

class Meat extends Thing<Thing<any>> {
  public declare meat: true;
}

class Beef extends Meat {
  public declare beef: true;
}

class Food<T extends Meat> extends Thing<T> {
  public declare food: true;
}

class Steak extends Food<Beef> {
  do() {
    this.thing; // ✔️,       derives from `Food → Thing`
    this.meat;  // ❌, should derive from `Beef → Meat`
    this.beef;  // ❌, should derive from `Beef`
    this.food;  // ✔️,       derives from `Food`
  }
}
```

I have tried:

- **Mapped types directly in class**

  1. **Works** — No
  2. **Direct** — No
  3. **Stable** — No

  These are the two variations I tried first. No luck.

  ```
  class Food<T extends Meat> extends Thing<T> {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]; // ']' expected. ts(1005)
  }
  ```

  ```
  class Food<T extends Meat> extends Thing<T> {
    [K in T]: T[K]; // A mapped type may not declare properties or methods. ts(7061)
  }
  ```
- **Type aliases**

  1. **Works** — Yes
  2. **Direct** — No
  3. **Stable** — No

  I came up with this type merge alias. It works, sort of, but has multiple caveats:

  1. It needs to be applied to the extended class (`Steak`) instead of the base class (`Food`)
  2. It requires `Food`'s generic parameter (`<T extends Meat>`), otherwise typescript will throw `Base constructors must all have the same return type. ts(2510)`.

  ```
  type Cooked<T extends Meat> = (new (
    ...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Food>
  ) => Food<T> & T) &
    typeof Food;

  class Steak extends (Food as Cooked<Beef>) {
    do() {
      this.thing; // true
      this.meat; // true
      this.beef; // true
      this.food; // true
    }
  }
  ```

  [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=26&pln=19&pc=13#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-WJUBA5FbtK1MaIAApiIHYQi-dBmpkaYpiiW0Zj2V0MNP2hjguzQUFqJPYFPQXMqIWQGAAZUIYGtAydRlzuxgVo0tsl+SKtHs0UEGiMA7UbCkU2ZE7QSmgO1a2DHb0nqR8s-nRqXE4gzMaRXX3QXW6QO71EoPGUXbCcTiAA)
- ***Illegal* generic-extending interface**

  1. **Works** — Yes
  2. **Direct** — Yes
  3. **Stable** — No

  This one is the most interesting, as it seems to work 100%. However, it requires a `// @ts-expect-error` directive in order to suppress the errors it produce. This really doesn't sit right with me.

  ```
  // without `// @ts-expect-error`:
  //   Interface 'Food<T>' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Thing<T>' and 'T'.
  //    Named property 'input' of types 'Thing<T>' and 'T' are not identical. ts(2320)

  // @ts-expect-error
  interface Food<T extends Meat> extends T {}

  class Food<T extends Meat> extends Thing<T> {
    public declare food: true;
  }

  class Steak extends Food<Beef> {
    do() {
      this.thing; // true
      this.meat; // true
      this.beef; // true
      this.food; // true
    }
  }
  ```

  Attempting to use `Omit` to remove the overlapping properties stops it from working outright:

  ```
  // An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members. ts(2312)
  interface Food<T extends Meat> extends Omit<T, keyof Thing> {}
  ```

  [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgcwDy2gUwB4BdtkATGBFDMZATwD5boBvAKGmgAcBXAIxEWGjFsoMACds0fEjQAuSaM7YA3M1bRgAe2QR8C4Pg2iAFF179oKLvjmwAlEwC+zJ8xFRoAWWxh8OAkVI4aQxyNHQqOgYWNlM+ASERcWgAW29reUUVFzcYACFsbAAzP0ISGC8fJjVY8wTwJO4CwrldTOdVAHoO6AB3RCkNTl8AAy7oAAF8CABaPHZhfFnRUUNhmWYxtgBJZEJRQrBgCQByADENDWJMWmP1KmQNXwhEZM4QfCpsQYgQahKAyTUeYwY6hEI3aBUYjQUHHAB0G26bGgADkwKloewVvNRPg-sdLENbhpinjgTCwddblCKdSkg9fIghLt+GAQHDJBAjAAmADM3IADLZERMprNcPN9EsVqJmCg9gcjtBzpdMP8yp40gw8KVAlhGNlwO4VVcsDqAuUteq9cFrlUYjw4oJhPUJIULsQWgplO1XEaYABlQhgADW1pgJvQ+SKUTUxA0Rns0WRUkQEDhqbQSmgY1a2DUbFT6dSPmzue9BckSHTjSKZe6ecrRbh7su9Yy+bYTicQA)

Comment: In order to make `mixin` consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nlv3lW) example and\or [this](https://catchts.com/oop-style) article

Comment: Btw, how do you want to create an instance of `Thing` class ?It is recursive and it expects self instance as an argument

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine Your mixin example does work for mixing properties, but it loses the main functionality of accepting an object in the constructor to be spread into the class, similar to object initializers in C# — `constructor(public input: T) {}`. Referring back to my example, `Steak#input` should be of type `Beef`, not `Thing`, & instantiation would look something like: `new Steak({ beef: true, meat: true, thing: true })`